# error: VM2713:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Why I've got this error `VM2713:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0` but i've successfully updated the database table?The error was `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0` in my console. I insert some data but at the same time i'm updating some data from database table. Can you help me with this guys? thank you in advance.

Here's my code

```
 $larea = $proloc_larea." ".$_POST['areatype'];
 $rpu = $_GET['rpudata'];

 $rpu_id = $_GET['rpu_id'];

 $arr = explode(",",$rpu_id);

 $property_array2 = array(
    'view_flag' => 0,
     );
     $c = '';



$barcode = time();

$property_array = array('sitio' => $proloc_sitio,
                    'loc_street' => $proloc_street,
                    'loc_province' => $add_provz,
                    'view_flag' => 1
                    );

 if(($property_array['land_area']!= " ") || !empty($property_array['land_area'])){


    foreach($arr as $r){
        $b = trim($r);
        $c = $b;

    $con2 = "OCPC_ID='".$c."'";
    $result2 = $db->update('property_information',$property_array2,$con2);
        //echo $c;
    }

    $result = $db->insert('property_information',$property_array);

    //echo $result;
    if ($result) {
        $response = array(
            'result2' => $result2,
            'error' => false,
            'message' => 'Successfully inserted',
            'barcode' => $barcode
        );
        echo json_encode($response,true);die();
    }
    else{
        $response = array(
            'error' => true,
            'message' => 'error',
            'barcode' => $barcode
        );
        echo json_encode($response,true);die();
    }




}else {
    $response = array(
        'error' => true,
        'message' => 'some fields are not filled.'
    );
        echo json_encode($response,true);die();
}
```

Here's my success in ajax

```
success: function(resback){
      var res = $.parseJSON(resback);
      if(res.error==false) {
        $('#property').hide(); 
        var modal = $('#blabla');
        modal.modal('show');
            modal.find('input[name="cs_barcode"]').val(res.barcode);
      } else {
        alert(res.message);
      }
    }
```

The error was `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0` in my console. I insert some data but at the same time i'm updating some data from database table. Can you help me with this guys? thank you in advance.

Comment: i'm sorry sir but i don't understand this. I'm new in javascript and ajax T_T

Comment: your `resback` is undefined I guess, check it.

Comment: i've alerted the `resback` and the result was `UPDATE property_information SET view_flag='0' WHERE OCPC_ID='75'successUPDATE property_information SET view_flag='0' WHERE OCPC_ID='103'success{"result2":true,"error":false,"message":"Successfully inserted","barcode":1503385013}`

Comment: Well that's not valid JSON. Hence the parse fails. And probably don't want to pass back the actual sql query to your client if not necessary.

Comment: @newBee the result was `UPDATE property_information SET view_flag='0' WHERE OCPC_ID='75'successUPDATE property_information SET view_flag='0' WHERE OCPC_ID='103'success{"result2":true,"error":false,"message":"Successfully inserted","barcode":1503385168}`

Comment: this response is not valid json, that's why you are getting that error. for more check [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)

Comment: okay sir thank you ^_^

Comment: Use one of the many JSON validators around http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/. especially the `UPDATE property_ ... _OCPC_ID='103'success` is no proper JSON

Comment: okay sir thanks ^_^